# Use JAXB-RI with Jersey

Tags: jaxb, jersey

I am using the xjc ant task provided by the JAXB-RI to generate our jaxb classes and provide all the jaxb jars in with my web application's WEB-INF/lib folder. Jersey is still using the runtime provided jaxb implementation (found in rt.jar) Is there some way to use @Provider to force it to use the jaxb-ri jars?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem correctly, [this small tutorial](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Migrating_JAXB_2_0_applications_to_JavaSE_6.html) should help.